# How to extract information from HT1621B LCD Driver

Tags: microcontroller, character-lcd

This is my first post so I apologize if I mess this up and am trying to keep this short. I have a rangefinder that I would like to retrieve the output data from. [This is the datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/96976/HOLTEK/ht1621b.html) for the chip and I was wondering if I would need to use all SEG and COM outputs to retrieve the printed range or if I could just use a select few to retrieve the desired signals. If so, is there any hardware that may be helpful for it?

Comment: You will probably have to reverse engineer it just hook up a logic analyzer to the lines and see if you can make sense of it

Comment: If you can access the SEG and COM outputs, did you consider to observe the interface to the CPU/MCU? That could be much easier. -- BTW, Trying to keep things short is not always the right approach. We need enough information to be able to help at all, and better too much than missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a microcontroller (or a small FPGA) to sniff the digital inputs and create a mirror of the 32 x 4 RAM inside the LCD driver chip that represent a bitmap of LCD segment states. That can then be decoded and interpreted.

Maximum data clock frequency for the LCD driver is only 300kHz so it's not all that demanding for a microcontroller with a reasonably high clock frequency.

If you don't have an oscilloscope handy to observe the signals, a typical super-inexpensive '24MHz' logic analyzer with open-source Sigroc Pulseview software would be fine.

In comparison to the straightforward transfer of data to the LCD driver, there are complex 'analog-y' AC waveforms on the COM and SEG lines that would not be much fun to try to figure out. Image from [TI](https://software-dl.ti.com/lprf/sensor_controller_studio/docs/cc13x2_cc26x2_help/html/lcd_controller__1.html).

[image]

You'll still have to figure out which of the 128 bits of RAM corresponds to which LCD segment though. I would be tempted to just inject a signal in to probe each bit using an external MCU (you could use an Arduino or whatever). I don't think it will be as straightforward an arrangement as an LED display driver would typically be, because of the way segments and commons are typically connected inside the LCD glass.

Comment: There's only 128 bits of unknown data if you can set up a realtime display of those values it should be falrly easy to get the LCD dispay to show chosen values, and then attack the bits one at a time, eg "0.9" vs "0.8" is different by one segment then try 0.3, 0.2 etc...   your basic known plaintext attack

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні My assumption is that this driver is connection to some kind of instrumentation black box that cannot be controlled. It's almost 100% sure that a number of the segment 'positions' are unused and (probably more of an issue with trying to use existing hardware/firmware to probe) some may be very rarely used (for example, an overtemperature or other rarely triggered alarm annunciator segment).

Comment: I get the impression that the instrument is a portable distance measurer, which can easily be manipulated to give predictable readings.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні  Could be.  In any case, it's usually possible to see the annunciators (if any) in the display with the right lighting and make sure that every state has been covered.